# HostUnreachableError on starting logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

Error occured while starting logstash :

```
 elasticsearch - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error.
{:url=>"http://localhost:9200/", 
:error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError,
 :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://localhost:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] 
Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
```

I am starting the logstash by :

```
sudo ./logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/beat.conf --config.reload.automatic
```

Also I have tested the config too by :

```
sudo ./logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/beat.conf --config.test_and_exit
```

Test returns CONF OK

How to solve this error? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. My elasticsearch service got stopped. Thanks